# connect to gmail in python via imaplib

Tags: python, linux, server, gmail, imaplib

I have a python script that downloads daily attachments from a specific email address from gmail.
Everything works great locally. The problem occurs when I try to upload it to the server.

Code below:

```
import email
import os
import imaplib
import socket



def download_attachments():
    print('Connect with IMAP')
    imap_server = imaplib.IMAP4_SSL('imap.gmail.com')

    print('Login details')
    username = "email@gmail.com"
    password = "password"


    print('Login to mail')
    try:
        imap_server.login(username, password)
    except imaplib.IMAP4.error as error:
        return (f'Error while login: {error}')
```

after running the code on the server, it shows me in the console

> Connect with IMAP

and nothing else happens.

Server details

> Production Python scripts server.
>
> Updated             : Sat 14 Jan 2023 02:55:01 PM CET Hostname
> : xxxxxxx IP address          : xxxxxxx System type         : Debian
> GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) Load                : 0.02 0.06 0.07 1/114
> 59615 HW resources        : 2 CPU | 3931 MB RAM
>
> debug2: client_check_window_change: changed debug2: channel 0: request
> window-change confirm 0 debug3: send packet: type 98 Last login: Sat
> Jan 14 14:19:25 2023 from xxxxxxx This system is managed by Ansible,
> all local changes will be lost.
>
> Production Python scripts server.
>
> Updated             : Sat 14 Jan 2023 02:55:01 PM CET Hostname
> : xxxxxxx IP address          : xxxxxxx System type         : Debian
> GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye) Load                : 0.02 0.06 0.07 1/114
> 59615 HW resources        : 2 CPU | 3931 MB RAM

Comment: If the code works locally, something in your server or the network its provided with is the issue.  Most likely the server has firewall rules blocking the outbound access to gmail's imap port ..

Comment: PS. Set "timeout" value to something sane for https://docs.python.org/3/library/imaplib.html#imaplib.IMAP4_SSL call - it is None by default and call will block until connection is established ..

Comment: thanks rasjani
i set timeout value and now i get 
OSError: [Errno 99] Cannot assign requested address

Comment: Still thinking its an issue in your server .. Login into  the server you are running your code and try "telnet imap.gmail.com 993" and if that opens the connection, then issue is somewhere in your code - if that fails, complain to the server admin..

Comment: Is this the only code, or some more code? I was looking for a call to `download_attachments()`

Comment: Do you use 2-Step-Verification with the google account that you are using in the code?